# How can I find Replication Bytes Per second in SQL 2005?

Tags: sql-server-2005, replication

Is there an easy way to get a bytes per second measurement for replication?  I am trying to get a mesuarment for some networking people.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This isn't what I'd call "easy", but just set up a table with some data in one database, and replicate the table while recording how long it takes.  The actual number of bytes that have to be sent will be larger than the size of all the data combined, but it's probably a good enough measure for the networking crowd.